# how to show that matrix B is invertible and specific to a particular summation

Tags: numerical-methods

I need to show that if the matrix $A$ is invertible, and $\|B-A\| < \|A^{-1}\|^{-1}$, then $B$ is invertible.

I was able to prove that B is invertible $$(A^{-1}B)^{-1} = B^{-1}A = (I-A^{-1}B)^k$$, thus $$B^{-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} {(I-A^{-1}B)^k A^{-1}}$$

However, I am unsure  how can I show that there also exists a $$B^{-1} = A^{-1} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} {(I - BA^{-1})^k}$$  Any idea on how to do so?

Any feedback on this question would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  $$ \|I -  B A^{-1})\| = \|(A - B) A^{-1}\| \le \ldots < 1$$ 
so your series converges in norm.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $ \| A^{-1}B- I \| = \|A^{-1}(B-A)\| \leq \|A^{-1}\|\|B-A\| < 1 $. Thus we have $$ \|\sum_{k=0}^\infty (I-A^{-1}B)^k\| \leq \sum_{k=0}^\infty \|(I-A^{-1}B)^k\|\leq \sum_{k=0}^\infty \|I-A^{-1}B\|^k < \infty $$( being a GP series with common ratio less than 1). So $  C = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (I-A^{-1}B)^k $ is well defined and we can verify that 
$$ A^{-1}BC = (I-(I-A^{-1}B)C = I $$ Thus $ A^{-1}B $ is invertible and hence $B$ is invertible.